# Solver breaks down with variables

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have been struggling with a this problem for the past couple of weeks. I am working on solving a series of ODEs in Python for a research project I am on. (The python code has to imitate MATLAB code that came before it.)

The relevant segment is here:

```
def dy (t,y,params):

    dy = np.zeros(3)

    wL = params[0]
    T = params[1]
    CH4 = params[2]
    k = params[3]
    ka = params[4]
    H = params[5]
    kmt = params[6]
    E = params[7]
    d = params[8]
    y0 = params[9]

#    dy[1] = 1500000 - 0 - 9.987338917338950e-11*y[1]*1000000
#    - 1.437829040671314e-17*y[1]*9.84e11

     dy[1] = E[1]-y[1]*d[1]
     - k[1]*y[1]*y0[14]
     - k[55]*y[1]*y0[37]

     dy[2] = 0 - 0 + 9.987338917338950e-11*y[1]*1000000 
     - 7.742358922306635e-12*y[2]*0 + 0.7*7.432069505555159e-12*0*1000000
     -3.5e-15*(0 + 0)*y[2] - 2* 7e-16*y[2]**2 


     return dy
```

Which works with:

```
y = np.zeros(3)
ode15s = ode(dy)

y[1] = 2.46e10
ode15s.set_initial_value(y)
ode15s.set_f_params(params)
ode15s.set_integrator('vode', method = 'bdf')
```

The commented out lines work correctly, but the uncommented equivalent lines with variables instead of variables do not work correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: We need to see how you created `params` to know what is going wrong.  The problem may be that indexing in Matlab is 1-based while in Python it is 0-based.  That is, if `y = np.zeros(3)`, the three elements of `y` are `y[0]`, `y[1]` and `y[2]`.  In the function `dy`, you haven't assigned a value to `dy[0]`.  Is that intentional?  (By the way, it is a bad practice to use a variable that is the same name as the function.)  And perhaps where you refer to `E[1]`, you should used `E[0]`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say it does not work correctly?  Do you get an error? (If so, please show the complete error message.)  Or do you get a solution that you know is wrong?

Comment: The indexing is correct, the [0] values of each variable are 0 to keep it in line with MATLAB (even though this may be bad practice, it doesn't really matter for the end result). And it doesn't work correctly as in I get a solution i know is wrong.

Comment: params was created by:
    params = [None] * 10
    params[0] = wL
    .
    .
    .

Comment: It still doesn't work if i initialize params as an empty list and then use the append method to add each variable.

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question so the code is a SSCCE (sscce.org), so someone can copy it and run it and reproduce the problem.  (Of course, it won't really be "correct", because you know the solution that it is generating is wrong.)  Also, in the `dy` function, you could simply print `E[1]`, `d[1]` and the other parameters that are used to compute `dy[1]` to verify that they have the values that you expect them to.

Comment: By the way, I assume that the three lines shown in the question that compute `dy[1]` are actually a single line in the source file.  As written above, the code computes `dy[1] = E[1]-y[1]*d[1]`.  The next two lines are evaluated, but then ignored, because they are not part of the previous expression, and they are not assigned to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source code contains code exactly like this:

```
     dy[1] = E[1]-y[1]*d[1]
     - k[1]*y[1]*y0[14]
     - k[55]*y[1]*y0[37]
```

then the problem is that `dy[1]` is being computed as `dy[1] = E[1] - y[1]*d[1]`, and the next two lines are (effectively) ignored.  They are valid python expressions, but they are not part of the previous line, and they are not assigned to anything, so the values are ignored.

Any of the following will fix that problem:

- Make it one line:

  ```
   dy[1] = E[1]-y[1]*d[1] - k[1]*y[1]*y0[14] - k[55]*y[1]*y0[37]
  ```
- Enclose the entire expression in parentheses:

  ```
   dy[1] = (E[1]-y[1]*d[1]
            - k[1]*y[1]*y0[14]
            - k[55]*y[1]*y0[37])
  ```
- Use a line continuation character (`\`) at the end of the lines to be continued:

  ```
   dy[1] = E[1]-y[1]*d[1] \
   - k[1]*y[1]*y0[14]     \
   - k[55]*y[1]*y0[37]
  ```